# Connect Highcharts step line to and from the x extremes

Tags: highcharts

Let say I have a 2 points in the middle of chart area connected with step line:

```
------------------
|                |
|         *      |
|         |      |
|   *-----|      |
|                |
------------------
```

I actually want the connection line to start at the x axis min value (and y value of the first point of serie) and to end at the x axis max value (and the y value of the last point in serie):

```
------------------
|                |
|         *------|
|         |      |
|---*-----|      |
|                |
------------------
```

Can I achieve this somehow declaratively in serie definition?

My alternative solution is to draw artificial (and invisible) point at the x min and x max (and keep those shifted as needed).

**Edit:**
I ended up solving this by inserting continuously updated artificial points (first and last).

Comment: I think that the best solution is to use additional points in your xAxis min and max.

Comment: You are saying `y` axis, but your illustrations seem to imply the `x` axis - can you clarify which you want to affect?